# User's way to disable 'prefers-color-scheme' or Dark Mode?

Tags: css, google-chrome, userscripts, darkmode

I've seen a ton of Q&As on this site about how programmers can turn dark mode of their web pages on and off.

**But how do I, as a user, disable dark mode for my browser?**

---

I'm used to having my OS set to a dark theme, but I want my browser's pages to default to a light theme.

I tried `chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark`
Also tried `chrome.exe --disable-features=DarkMode`
None of them have any effect. (February 2023, Chrome 110)

I know that many web pages decide whether to enable dark mode by reading `prefers-color-scheme`, but this seems to be a value that cannot be changed.

I also know that in DevTools it can be enabled by "Emulate CSS media feature `prefers-color-scheme: light`". But it can't be persisted and automated - which means I have to enable DevTools and enable emulating for every new page opened.

So far, is there any way to disable dark mode for web pages other than turning off the dark mode of the operating system?